# CSS Selector with random ids

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to automate some data creation within our platform for demonstrations.  I am trying to select an element that has random ID's that are generated each time a new item is created so I am trying to find a way to identify the element in a different way but having a hard time.

Here are a few CSS selectors for review:

```
css=#r59467f56-f0fa-491f-b212-11d354160319 > div > div > div.contents-wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > header > span > div`=

css=#r685f3f44-4eff-43b8-b5f6-57a2f0ecabde > div > div > div.contents-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > header > span > div
```

Any help that you can provide for a way to overcome this issue.  I want to sequence through each child element that gets created as part of the routine.

Comment: Try to locate elements with class selector if you don't want to do using ids

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read How to Ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  I'm guessing this is a ReactJS app.  Your best bet is to ask your devs to add attributes for you to use as locators (e.g. name or data- attributes).  There's other ways to locate elements (e.g. class, xpath), but it'll be less deterministic.  YMMV and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any specific reason why using css selectors?If no, you try xpath sibling concept or parent child concept in order to identify it.